# Updating form fields using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

Problem: How can I update a form's select input values and text input fields based on a MySQL query after select input's onchange event is fired?

What I've tried: 
I have tried to use AJAX with post and get data types, calling a php file that runs the query and echoes the results. Nothing displays. Any errors I have gotten along the way are usually small things that result in server 500 error. I have placed console.log statements in the function that runs the JQuery AJAX request. The change event was detected, the ajax success was called. I also tried using .load(), with GET and POST, no luck either. I have other features that implement AJAX, and I've tried modifying them to fit this scenario and have been unsuccessful.

I also tried to only use a select input that when changed would use AJAX request and .load function to display the other inputs which would be formatted on the php side and echoed to page with selected and values reflecting the db result.

What I want: 
I would like a simple example of a form with a select input with three options, text type input, and a submit button. The form is a client backend form to send updates to the MySQL db. Each input represents a filed in the db. The idea is that when the user changes the select inputs selected value, a query is done that uses the selected value for only returning one result. Each field of that one records values in db should now be reflected in the form. First, tell me if this is the correct way to approach this problem, and if not show me how you would.

Example index.php:

```
    <form action="editForm.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <select id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Select Contact" required>
            <option value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
            <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
            <option value="George Washington"></option>
        </select>    
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
        <input type="text" name="race" placeholder="Select Race" required>
        <select id="veteran_status" name="veteran_status" placeholder="Select Veteran Status" required>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

When on change event for #contact_name is fired I need to update the fields with the values the db has.

How would you implement this? Thanks in advance.

Update: as requested here is my JQuery code, but I know my example doesn't use the same names.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#currency_select').on('change', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'getCurrentValues.php',
        data: {currency: 'EUR'},
        success: function () {
          console.log('ajax was submitted');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my understanding of how to do this:

First, detect event and pass data via ajax for the query to retrieve record. This is in the document ready function to ensure DOM is ready.

```
     $("#contact_name).on("change", function(e){
       $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'editForm.php',
        data: {name: this.value},
        success: function () {
          console.log('ajax was submitted');
        }
      });
    };
```

editForm.php:

```
    include 'includes/db.php';
    $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $lastValues = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $age = $row['age'];
        }

        <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>">


        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: do I understand you correct that you want to choose "john smith" and get his age,race and veteran status loaded into the form so that you can edit it? if you you normaly make an on.("change") ajax call which you said you already tried.. you would then send the selected value to the file -> make your database query -> and then either replace the complete form (you would just have to create that form in your php file) OR send back an array with the age, race and status and populate the fields.. but please post some jquery code of what you tried..

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. One sec I'll post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your index:

```
<select id="contact_name" placeholder="Select Contact" required>
            <option value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
            <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
            <option value="George Washington"></option>
</select>  

<form action="editForm.php" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<select name="contact_name" id="contact_form" placeholder="Select Contact" required>
            <option value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
            <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
            <option value="George Washington"></option>
</select> 
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
        <input type="text" id="race" name="race" placeholder="Select Race" required>
        <select id="veteran_status" name="veteran_status" placeholder="Select Veteran Status" required>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    $("#contact_name").on("change", function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#form").load("formdata.php?contact="+selected); //normaly you do that with an id as value

        OR

        $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"formdata.php",
           data: {user: selected},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(response){
              if(response.status == "success") {
                 $("#age").val(response.age);
                 $("#race").val(response.race); 
                 $("#veteran_status").val(response.status);
              } else {
                 alert("No data found for this user!");
           }
        });
    });
```

and in your formdata.php file

```
//make your db-query
then either make the actual input fields which will be displayed if you use load

OR make something like if you use the ajax version

if($result) {
   echo json_encode(array("status" => "success",age" => $result["age"], "race" => $result["race"], "status" => $result["status"]));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed"));
}
```

also you can delete the action, method and enctype in your form, as this will be set in the ajax function ;)

I would advice you to use the userid as the value in your select field, and you will also need to either also fill the contact_name IN the form OR make an hidden input field so that you can submit the form and know whos data this is..

Comment: I added some code to my original post. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: This should work. Just keep in mind that the Ajax request is asynchronous. The jQuery Ajax call has more then just success method, you should cover even the possibility that there will be something wrong with error() function - check http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: @Christopher Supertramp could you please draw out the formatdata.php example if the ajax version is used?

Comment: yes if you echo out this json array you will get the results in the success function like i wrote e.g. ersponse.age and so on.. I will update it also so that you can check if there is data (but actually there should be data, as the select field should be populated from the database also)

Answer (score 1):

just echo the $age variable in your editForm.php file and in the AJAX call success function alert the response. like so-

**editForm.php**

```
include 'includes/db.php';
$name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $lastValues = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $age = $row['age'];
    }
  }
?>
```

**Ajax file**

```
$("#contact_name).on("change", function(e){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'editForm.php',
    data: {name: this.value},
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This worked. Christopher's answer got me in the right direction, but I did use part of your solution as well because I don't like JSON format.

Comment: with json you can access different fields like age, race, status in your ajax response. And can directly hook them to the html document using jquery.

Comment: can you give me an example? Also how do I change the selected option in a select element with the response?

Comment: ok then thanks... I may be overthinking it. It Chris' example he just echoes a json encoded array. I guess it is that simple. I tend to overthink it. I'll try using the JSON format now